# How to define measurement units in grass

Tags: grass-gis, measurements, units

I need to get the length and area of some landscape features in the US. My data was in lat and long degrees. I created a new location with an UTM projection and read the data into grass.

Now if I use the measure distance tool in the Map Display it appears in degrees. If I make a new column in the attribute table and then calculate the area, I also am not able to get something like square miles or kilometers.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the location projection (UTM in meters), not on the shapefile projection (in degrees) and GRASS GIS does not allow reprojection on the fly (look at [GRASS wiki: Map Reprojection](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Map_Reprojection))

You need to:

1) first create a location in the projection of your shapefile (in degrees)
2) import the shapefile into this location
3) within your new location (UTM), use [v.proj](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.proj.html) to reproject the layer from the import location to the destination location.

Comment: Note: In GRASS GIS 7 you can measure in metric units also in LatLong locations, see http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/WxPython-based_GUI_for_GRASS#Map_measure_tool