# r.univar - which format for working in GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis

As part of a cut and fill-procedure,I want to run the command r.univar, but it returns with no output. I´ve been comparing the properties in the rasterlayer (rasterized vector-layer) with another well working rasterlayer from the North Carolina-datapackage. Question is if I´m converting (rasterizing) the vectorlayer in the wrong way? Here I list the examples of both layers,- 1 from the NC-datapackage (working) and 2, my own file (not working). I see some differences there, but what am i doing wrong?

### 1, working:

```
Driver
GDAL provider
GTiff
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
C:\Users\Morck\Dropbox\Arbejde\GIS-tutorials\GrassDATABASE\Diverse\ElevationKopi
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Band 1
COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_0=5.557879e+001 7.572901e+001 0 191 191 0 255 0
COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_1=7.572901e+001 9.587922e+001 0 255 0 255 255 0
COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_2=9.587922e+001 1.160294e+002 255 255 0 255 127 0
COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_3=1.160294e+002 1.361797e+002 255 127 0 191 127 63
COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_4=1.361797e+002 1.563299e+002 191 127 63 20 20 20
COLOR_TABLE_RULES_COUNT=5
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=128.96199035645
STATISTICS_MEAN=127.18390324034
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=124.20372009277
STATISTICS_STDDEV=1.2340091242347
Dimensions
X: 700 Y: 750 Bands: 1
Origin
638300,220750
Pixel Size
1,-1
No Data Value
nan 
Data Type
Float32 - Thirty two bit floating point 
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=lcc +lat_1=36.16666666666666 +lat_2=34.33333333333334 +lat_0=33.75 +lon_0=-79 +x_0=609601.22 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
638300.0000000000000000,220000.0000000000000000 : 639000.0000000000000000,220750.0000000000000000
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet
```

### 2, not working

```
Driver
GDAL provider
GTiff
GeoTIFF
Dataset Description
C:\Users\Morck\Dropbox\Arbejde\GIS-tutorials\GrassDATABASE\Diverse\VandløbstraceRasterized.tif
AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Band 1
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1
STATISTICS_MEAN=0.45934734513274
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.49834462137385
Dimensions
X: 226 Y: 256 Bands: 1
Origin
695219,6.18746e+06
Pixel Size
1,-1
No Data Value
*NoDataValue not set* 
Data Type
Float64 - Sixty four bit floating point 
Pyramid overviews
Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs
Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
695219.1304354381281883,6187204.6521555976942182 : 695445.1304354381281883,6187460.6521555976942182
Band
Band 1
Band No
1
No Stats
No stats collected yet
```

Comment: Have you adjusted the region ?

Comment: Yep. Certain that it must be when rasterizing my vectorlayer.

Comment: The two rasters are in the same LOCATION/MAPSET (Diverse) but the projections are different which is not correct [How to define measurement units in grass](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/118084/how-to-define-measurement-units-in-grass/118109#118109)

Comment: That's right, they are from to different mapsets and locations, but that shouldn't conflict, but I'm not sure. They are not used together. I'm rasterizing the vector layer from within QGIS to ASCII and I'm not confident if this procedure is correct.

Comment: GRASS GIS is not QGIS look at [GRASS GIS Quickstart](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/helptext.html)

Comment: I do know that. I've been working with GRASS GIS the last couple of weeks and trying to find out the powers in it. Normally I work daily in my profession with MapInfo and QGIS. Rasterizing I therefore know from within QGIS. So I need to get on the right path here. GRASS has a lack on good tutorials besides the manual.

Comment: You cannot have 2 rasters with different projections in the same location (C:\Users\Morck\Dropbox\Arbejde\GIS-tutorials\GrassDATABASE\Diverse\) `+proj=lcc +lat_1=36.16666666666666...` and `+proj=utm +zone=32...`

Comment: About adjusting region i did this "manually" and not by running g.region, which seems to solve the problem. @Gene, your suggestion from the beginning were correct. Could you add it as an answer thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `g.region` on each raster before computations